# Asynchronous Server, Handle Disconnections while waiting for callbacks

Tags: sql, c, asynchronous, tcp, unix-socket

i have one question according to asynchronous server management. I am using **libevent2** and (for my own learning experience) plain ANSI C.
I do my stresstests with ab from the apache2 utils. Mostly `-n 10000` and `-c 400`. 
My database is a sql server on a debian computer in my local network. So the connection is pretty fast.
I profile my app also with valgrind (`--leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes`)

I have one issue now.
When I do synchronous calls to the sql database than everything works fine. But it is all done on the main thread, so it takes some time for new clients to receive data (while the stress is running). 
When I do asynchronous calls to the sql database than everything works fine as well, as long as no client disconnects BEFORE the sql call returns. As soon as the sql call returns and the client is disconnected already, i get a lot of invalid read erros (of course) because its buffer is freed already, the socket is closed etc. I tried a lot of different things already but couldn't get a proper solution.

I just wanted to ask in general how you handle stuff like this? Do you keep a BST for example, which includes all the clients connected and when an async call returns you search for it in it? If it is still in there u execute the callback otherwise discard it? I think this could kill performance quite a bit.
I also tried to check if the socket is still open, but it was kinda weird. 
`recv(fd, buffer, 1, MSG_PEEK)` always `returned -1` (on opened and closed non-blocking sockets)..

Well, it is kinda hard to explain what i did already so i just wait for what you guys will answer :-)

Greetings
Markus

update:
i just had the crazy idea to use a mutex for each connection. When i enter the async call i lock it, and release it after it returns.. :-) but i dont trust this method.. it doesnt sound right.. can anyone recommend that approach?

update 2: I tried my idea and it works great. It was a bit tricky to get it right but the locking did it

Comment: why are you using non-blocking sockets for the clients? just an idea, but why dont you go for a threaded model?

Comment: i felt in love with the nodeJS model :-) thats why... and libevent is great for supporting it. I can handle up to 4000 requests per second like this in a single thread. The problem is the SQL connection. it slows down incredibly. So i use worker threads to handle the SQL connection. It works fine if the connections stay on. If they exit and the sql callback comes i have a problem.

Comment: well, non-blocking its a headache... but if you like it. you should try to detect if a socket is closed BEFORE you write in it. if you post some code i can -maybe- give you a few pointers

Answer (score 0):

Lock per connection works fine, but it has a couple of drawbacks:

- the yield is one outstanding request per connection. That puts a limit to how much your application can scale.
- As you scale your number of connections, the number of mutexes the application has to create can be an issue as well.

The best bet is to decouple the "connections and client request management" from the "SQL query management", like you have mentioned. And that requires you to match responses with requests. As you go up in scale to serve hundreds of thousands of requests, the cost of the lookup will be insignificant. There are also ways to optimize this (e.g. a two level lookup, first for the client and then for the requests from that client). For the client lookup, you can assign an ID per client and implement a fast search operation.